# Best/Cleanest way to define constant lists or dictionaries

Tags: python, header, constants

I'm having trouble creating something which would be synonymous to a C header file (.h).

I have medium sized dictionaries and lists (about 1,000 elements), lengthy enums, and '#defines' (well not really), but I can't find a CLEAN way to organize them all. In C, I would throw them all in a header file and never think again about it, however, in Python that's not possible or so I think.

Current dirty solution: I'm initializing all constant variables at the top of either the module or function (module if multiple functions need it).

How can I cleanly organize constant variables?

Answer (score 29):

Put your constants into their own module:

```
# constants.py

RED = 1
BLUE = 2
GREEN = 3
```

Then import that module and use the constants:

```
import constants

print "RED is", constants.RED
```

The constants can be any value you like, I've shown integers here, but lists and dicts would work just the same.

Comment: Great idea. Do you know what the latency or efficiency loss is like? Because technically you're importing it and doesn't that require a look-up every time you reference the value?

Comment: You're doing an attribute lookup each time, which is the kind of operation that happens all the time anyway, it really isn't something to worry about.

Comment: @TSmith: And if you are super concerned with shaving off that little bit of time, you can always do `from constants import RED`, or assign it to a variable just before a super long loop: `red = constants.RED`

Comment: Thank you Ned and jdi! I really appreciate it and yeah jdi that's more of what I wanted to hear, but will a local variable get a copy or a reference to the globally imported constant? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @TSmith: don't go crazy with optimizations.  Chances are good your code isn't compute-bound, for example.

Comment: No it's not by any means but I'm trying to get a feel for pythons personality if you know what I'm saying.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I've done as suggested, putting all my constants in a file constants.py, importing them at the beginning of my script with import constants, but for some reason the constants are visible everywhere except in the main() function.  When I try to use `print constants.NUM_CELLS`
in main(), I get 
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'constants' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 16):

Usually I do this:

File: **constants.py**

```
CONSTANT1 = 'asd'
CONSTANT_FOO = 123
CONSTANT_BAR = [1, 2, 5]
```

File: **your_script.py**

```
from constants import CONSTANT1, CONSTANT_FOO
# or if you want *all* of them
# from constants import *

...
```

Now your constants are in one file and you can nicely import and use them.

Comment: If you import all of them, the constants become global variables and won't require a lookup. Do note that Python is about 200 times slower than C so you won't notice much of a speed boost if you try to micro optimize.

Comment: Thank you blender. Quick curiosity question, if I assign a local variable (within a function) to that imported global variable, will that local var have a copy or a reference to the global?

Comment: @TSmith: It will have a reference, but take note that the behavior will depend on whether its a mutable or immutable type. If its a string, any changes you make to that local will simply shadow the global constant. If the constant is say a list object, you can append to the local var and it will reflect in the constant because its still the same reference

Comment: @jdi: Yeah I learned about mutable and immutable types the hard way haha. Thank you so much for the help, I seriously appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Make a separate file `constants.py`, and put all globally-relevant constants in there. Then you can `import constants` to refer to them as `constants.SPAM` or do the (questionable) `from constants import *` to refer to them simply as `SPAM` or `EGGS`.

While we're here, note that Python doesn't support *constant* constants. The convention is just to name them in `ALL_CAPS` and promise not to mutate them.

Comment: Haha yeah I promise :), but what about run time efficiency? When you import a module is that like "__inline" in C?

Comment: @TSmith: I wouldn't compare it to an inline because its really just importing into a namespace module object, and it does it only once, and shares it in memory for subsequent imports.

Comment: Yes, that was a silly question now that I think about it. Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is fine, to take it one step further can use typings when defining your constants; you could just specify Final, or go a step further and provide Final[type] as well, e.g.:

```
from typing import Final, List
CONSTANT1: Final = 'asd'
CONSTANT_FOO: Final[int] = 123
ADLS_ENVIRONMENTS: Final[List[str]] = ["sandbox", "dev", "uat", "prod"]

# etc.
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/#the-final-annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mess with nested constants and don't like dicts, I came up with this fun solution:

```
# Recursively transform a dict to instances of the desired class

import json
from collections import namedtuple

class DictTransformer():
    @classmethod
    def constantize(self, d):
        return self.transform(d, klass=namedtuple, klassname='namedtuple')

    @classmethod
    def transform(self, d, klass, klassname):
        return self._from_json(self._to_json(d), klass=klass, klassname=klassname)

    @classmethod
    def _to_json(self, d, access_method='__dict__'):
        return json.dumps(d, default=lambda o: getattr(o, access_method, str(o)))

    @classmethod
    def _from_json(self, jsonstr, klass, klassname):
        return json.loads(jsonstr, object_hook=lambda d: klass(klassname, d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

Ex:

```
constants = {
  'A': {
    'B': {
      'C': 'D'
    }
  }
}
CONSTANTS = DictTransformer.transform(d, klass=namedtuple, klassname='namedtuple')
CONSTANTS.A.B.C == 'D'
```

Pros:

- handles nested dicts
- can potentially generate other types of dicts/classes
- namedtuples provide immutability for constants

Cons:

- may not respond to .keys and .values if those are not provided on your klass (though you can sometimes mimic with ._fields and list(A.B.C))

Thoughts?

h/t to @hlzr and you guys for the original class idea