# Jupyter Notebook version of previous Stackoverflow Python Question - Best/Cleanest way to define Python Constants

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, modularization

I am writing a Python script in Jupyter notebook to run 20+ long SQL queries. I have defined the SQL query strings in a separate file queryStrings.ipynb and the main body of code is in file analytics2020.ipynb.

This old StackOverflow post describes a nice clean way to define lists of constants ion a sepertate file (see the last answer ... the one from Ned Batchelder)

[python-best-cleanest-way-to-define-constant-lists-or-dictionarys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111632/python-best-cleanest-way-to-define-constant-lists-or-dictionarys)

However this does not appear to work in Jupyter Notebook. I have created the two seperate files

1. queryStrings.ipynb

   ```
   q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration = '''
   with session_boundaries as (
   SELECT
       e.cust_id_attr_value
      ,e.event_timestamp
      ,DATEDIFF(minutes, LAG(e.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY e.cust_id_attr_value ORDER BY e.event_timestamp), e.event_timestamp) AS inactivity_time
      ,LAG(e.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY e.cust_id_attr_value ORDER BY e.event_timestamp) as prior_event_timestamp
   FROM
      APPLICATIONDB e
   WHERE
      event_data:"c-platform-m-os" = 'iOS' AND 
      event_timestamp BETWEEN \'{:s}\' AND \'{:s}\'
   )
   select 
       session_date,
       sum(num_sessions) as total_sessions,

    etc. etc. 
    '''
   ```
2. analytics2020.ipynb

   ```
   import pandas as pd



   import numpy as np

   from queryStrings import q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration

   print('===== q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration ====')

   print(q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration)
   ```

However, when I try running this I get an error:

```
26 from queryStrings import q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration
     27 print('===== q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration ====')
     28 print(q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queryStrings'
```

The previous post I quoted however tells me this ought to work. Perhaps it's I have a hunch that this is because these files are Jupyter Notebook .ipynb files rather than plain vanilla .py files.

Would appreciate any help resolving this! Thanks so much.

Comment: To get this to work, you need to either rename queryStrings.ipynb as .py or use the import-ipynb module (see [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file) for more details).

Comment: Is using Jupyter Notebooks a necessity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research found a way to do this in Jupyter using the %store class.

So in queryStrings.ipynb I added the line:

```
%store q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration
```

Then in analytics2020.ipynb I added then line

```
%store -r q_CurrWeekiOSDailySessionCountDuration
```

And then presto! It worked.