# How to make a list (or any other value) immutable: a real constant in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants, immutability, python-typing

In an [old discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111632/python-best-cleanest-way-to-define-constant-lists-or-dictionarys) I found the reference to typing `Final`. I tried the example [from the docs](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/qualifiers.html#semantics-and-examples):

```
y: Final[Sequence[str]] = ['a', 'b']
y.append('x')  # Error: "Sequence[str]" has no attribute "append"
z: Final = ('a', 'b')  # Also works
```

But opposing to the docs it mutates `y` to `['a','b','x']` without error. I'm on Python 3.11. What's going on? And moreover: What's the state of the art creating immutable constants in 2024 in Python?

Currently I use `@dataclass(frozen=True)` to accomplish immuability, but there might be more straight forward solutions.

The old discussions do not help with modern features of Python 3.10+.

Comment: You didn't read the paragraph immediately preceding that particular example, where it explicit says that `Final` prevents later *assignments* to the name, not modifications of the value initially assigned to it.

Comment: "Note that declaring a name as final only guarantees that the name will not be re-bound to another value, but does not make the value immutable. Immutable ABCs and containers may be used in combination with Final to prevent mutating such values:
"

Comment: And even the name rebinding will only be enforced by any static type checkers rather than the interpreter at runtime.

Comment: @chepner: "to prevent mutating such value" - states clearly that y.append() should lead to an error but it doesn't. Here is a gap between documentation and reality which is not answered here.

Comment: You're misreading it. It leads to a static type-checking error, not a runtime error. `y` has two types, in a sense: its *static type* is `Sequence[str]`, and its *dynamic* type is `list`. It's a static-type error because not all "real" types that are subclasses of `Sequence` have an `append` method, but it's not a dynamic-type error because at runtime `list.append` is defined. The "prevention" comes from `mypy` telling you that you are using `append` on a value you claimed (via the type hint) should not be allowed to use `append`, not from Python itself disallowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type checkers can only hint you ("statically") that you are doing something wrong here. In runtime, Python interpreter doesn't care about what type hints say. (Unless you're using libraries like Pydantic for example which enforces this but it's out of scope here)

Lets talk about `Final`. From documentation:

> The `typing.Final` type qualifier is used to indicate that a variable or attribute should not be **reassigned**, **redefined**, or **overridden**

It is talking about assignment for the label `y`! not mutating the object that `y` points to. `.append()` "*mutates*" the object. You still have your `y` pointing to the same list. So it doesn't prevent you. And that's why you don't see any error regarding this. That error comes from `Sequence`. If you want to mutate a sequence you should use `MutableSequence`.

You can use `tuple` instead of a mutable list (although they have other differences too) or create your own list-like class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22340603/13944524

Comment: Thanks. I went with @dataclass(frozen=True) for now. Unforunatelly the questions is closed despite it raises issued and asks for answers not available 9 years ago.

Comment: @Fred the frozen dataclass is the accepted answer to the second duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992808/5067311 . If you have _specific_ questions left unanswered, ask a new, _narrowly scoped_ question.